# Does Haar measure have such property?

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, additive-combinatorics, borel-sets, haar-measure

Suppose, $G$ is a locally compact topological group. $\mu$ is Haar measure on that group. $A$ and $B$ are Borel subsets of $G$, such that $\mu(A)$ and $\mu(B)$ are finite. 
Does the inequality $\mu(\{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}) \leq \mu(A)\mu(B)$ always hold?

The question seems to be correct as it is quite easy to prove by induction, that if $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets, then $\{ab | a \in A, b \in B\}$ is also a Borel set. However, I do not know, how to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you can show "by induction" that the product is Borel? How do you use induction? on what?

Comment: May be I misunderstood something? Consider the case where $G$ is the unit circle (on the complex plane). If $A=B$ is the half-circle consisting of the points with non-negative real parts, then $AB=G$. Yet $\mu(A)\mu(B)=(1/2)^2$? Assuming that the measure is normalized to have $\mu(G)=1$.

Comment: Are you really asking whether $\mu(AB)\le \mu(A)+\mu(B)$. That would, at least, be immune to not normalizing the measure :-)

Comment: Oh, but that inequality doesn't hold always either. Let $G$ be a torus, let $A$ and $B$ be the two loops, both of measure zero. Again $AB$ is the whole group. Nope. I don't see a related inequality that would always hold :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen any idea why the product is necessarily measurable?

Comment: I'm not sure the product always is measurable. If $A$ is a Vitali set on $[0,1)\times\{0\}$, and $B$ is a similar Vitali set on $\{0\}\times[0,1)$, then wouldn't countably many translates of $AB$ seamlessly cover $\Bbb{R}^2/\Bbb{Z}^2=[0,1)\times[0,1)$ implying that  $AB$ can't be measurable. Yet $A$ and $B$ alone are both null sets.

Comment: Scratch that. You did say *Borel* :-)

Comment: @Yanko : Borel induction, i.e. show that it holds for $A,B$ open (for instance); then fixing an open $A$ showing that if it holds for $B$ then it holds for $B^c$ and if it holds for all $B_n$ then it holds for $\bigcup_n B_n$. You get that it holds for open $A$ and Borel $B$; then you do a similar induction for a fixed Borel $B$ and move $A$ (I'm not saying that it works, I'm just saying that this would be the approach described by the word "induction")

Comment: @Max Thanks, I never heard about this "induction" method before.

Comment: @Yanko : the name "induction" isn't always used, sometimes authors just say "classical technique" or something of the sort. For an example where the name is used (and discussed in "full generality") Birkhoff uses that name in *Universal Algebra* for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not hold. Take $G=\{0,1\}$ with addition modulo 2 the counting measure times $1/100$ (this is a Haar measure indeed). So the measure of $G$ is $1/50$ the measure of $\{0\}$ is $1/100$ and so on.

Now let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Then $\mu(A)\cdot \mu(B)=1/10,000$ and it's clearly less than the measure of $A+B = G$.

Edit: It turns out that you don't even have to multiply by $1/100$ any normalized measure would work because $A\subseteq A+B$ and $\mu(B)<1$.